# Use github action to push in production with git push production

Tags: git, deployment, github-actions

I would like to migrate from bitbucket to github. I use bitbucket pipeline to manually send code in production with git push ssh://user@site:path master 
with is my bitbucket pipeline

```
clone:
  depth: full
pipelines:
  custom:
    deployment-to-prod:
     - step:
         deployment: production
         script:
           - git push ssh://user@site:path master
```

I would like to do the same think with github action but I don't know how to do it can you help me please ? Does someone has already did it ?

Thanls

Comment: Sorry, yes, I misunderstood what you wanted to do. I will delete my answer for now and repost an answer if I find anything that might help you.

Comment: `git push` to a ssh configured remote will likely work fine. You may just need to set the user and email with `git config` first. Have you tried it yourself yet?

Comment: Maybe this action can help https://github.com/ad-m/github-push-action